# Error Message: Incorrect Syntax near'.'. in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I write query am not find out the error in this query, please help me..

I am getting error:

> Error Message.Incorrect Syntax near'.'. error

for my query:

```
SELECT     
   dbo.EP_UserDetails.UserID, dbo.EP_UserDetails.EmpID, 
   dbo.EP_UserDetails.FirstName dbo.EP_UserDetails.LastName AS Name, 
   dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveType, dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.NoOfDays, 
   dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveAppliedFromDate, 
   dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveAppliedToDate, dbo.EP_User.MangerUserID
FROM         
   dbo.EP_User 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.EP_UserDetails ON dbo.EP_User.UserID = dbo.EP_UserDetails.UserID 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.EP_LeaveManagement ON dbo.EP_User.UserID = dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.UserID
```

Answer (score 3):

Comma needed between `FirstName` and `dbo.EP_UserDetails.` Or if you are trying to concatenate the two for full name you need to do that. Can't just have a space. I believe in SQLServer it's `+` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Add comma between dbo.EP_UserDetails.FirstName,dbo.EP_UserDetails.LastName

```
SELECT     dbo.EP_UserDetails.UserID, dbo.EP_UserDetails.EmpID, dbo.EP_UserDetails.FirstName,dbo.EP_UserDetails.LastName AS Name, 
                      dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveType, dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.NoOfDays, dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveAppliedFromDate, 
                      dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveAppliedToDate, dbo.EP_User.MangerUserID
```

Answer (score 0):

As Leeish told comma is missing that's it is generating problem, but my personal suggestion in this case please create table alias and use it as below:

```
SELECT     dbo.EUD.UserID, dbo.EUD.EmpID, dbo.EUD.FirstName, dbo.EUD.LastName AS Name, 
                      dbo.ELM.LeaveType, dbo.ELM.NoOfDays, dbo.ELM.LeaveAppliedFromDate, 
                      dbo.ELM.LeaveAppliedToDate, dbo.EU.MangerUserID
FROM         dbo.EP_User  EU INNER JOIN
                      dbo.EP_UserDetails  EUD ON dbo.EU.UserID = dbo.EUD.UserID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ELM  ELM ON dbo.EU.UserID = dbo.ELM.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your question is you are missing + sign to contact two field Firstname and Lastname.

Try this.

```
SELECT     dbo.EP_UserDetails.UserID, dbo.EP_UserDetails.EmpID, dbo.EP_UserDetails.FirstName + dbo.EP_UserDetails.LastName AS Name, 
                  dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveType, dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.NoOfDays, dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveAppliedFromDate, 
                  dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.LeaveAppliedToDate, dbo.EP_User.MangerUserID

  FROM         dbo.EP_User INNER JOIN
  dbo.EP_UserDetails ON dbo.EP_User.UserID = dbo.EP_UserDetails.UserID INNER JOIN
  dbo.EP_LeaveManagement ON dbo.EP_User.UserID = dbo.EP_LeaveManagement.UserID
```

Regards
AB Vyas